# Configure datasource type at runtime

Tags: quarkus

I have an application that uses a relational database and the database type is selected when the application is installed (between mysql, mariadb, mssql and oracle). The property `quarkus.datasource.db-kind` can only be defined at compile-time, so I don't really know how to get there without having to compile four copies of the same application. Any suggestion?

I understand why this should not be possible for a native image, but why is not possible even for a JIT artifact?

Marco.

Comment: Did you consider to produce different artifacts for your app? e. g. myapp-mysql, myapp-oracle. Those could differ dependencies and properties only and being packaged automatically according maven profiles, for example.

Comment: Yes, is what I'm doing right now. But the application itself is identical, so I have 4 clones of the same code with a different application.properties (and eventually the dependency to the jdbc connector)

Comment: Sounds ok. First, you have lighter jars. Second, this is more protected against user' configuration mistakes.

Comment: true, but to me is not really ideal having to compile it multiple times. The difference in size is neglectable and part of the configuration has still to be defined at runtime. It kinda bothers me, I'm using hibernate exactly because I don't want to define the database type at compile-time, yet here I'm forced to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have guessed correctly, this has been done to fully optimize the native executable case but it also allows for some optimizations in the JVM case.

For now, that's not something we are willing to change but you could open an enhancement request on our GitHub and see how many votes this gets.

Comment: Ok thanks, one more thing: If I'm building a fast-jar, would be safe during the installation phase to substitute just the jar in "app" while keeping the other folders ("lib" and "quarkus") unchanged? Or this optimization affects also what's in those folders?